# python ftplib error : Failed to setup connection

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using ftp upload function to upload files to my own ftp server , its keep through the following except ,

```
2015-12-10 11:35:22,985 - FtpUpload - Failed to setup connection
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "ftp_upload.py", line 122, in upload_queue
    queue.put(upload(ifn))
  File "ftp_upload.py", line 95, in upload
    upload_to_ftp(trans_dst,s3_dst)
  File "ftp_upload.py", line 53, in upload_to_ftp
    _ftp.connect(server_ip, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 135, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I've tested my ftp server with other dummy code and its working fine ,  here is my function ..

```
def upload_to_ftp(file_path, server_ip):
    try:
        #connection
        _ftp = ftplib.FTP()
        _ftp.connect(server_ip, port)
        #user and password vars must be in the config file
        _ftp.login(user=user, password=password)
        logger.info("Connecting to ftp server...")
    except:
        logger.error("Failed to setup connection")
        raise
    logger.info("Starting to upload %s to %s" % (file_path, server_ip))
    upload_file = open(file_path, 'r')
    try:
        path_split = file_path.split('/')
        file_name = path_split[len(path_split) - 1]

        _ftp.storbinary('STOR '+ file_path, upload_file, 1024)
        logger.info("File %s is uploaded." % file_path)
        upload_file.close()
    except:
        logger.error("Upload to FTP failed")
        upload_file.close()
```

the upload function is here :

```
def upload(ifn):
    """ Upload Function."""

    create_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

    ifn_norm = resub('[ !@#$%\t"#$%&\()*\-/<=>?@^_`{|},.:]', '-', ifn).lower() + os.path.splitext(ifn)[1]

    src = "%s/%s" % (src_loc,ifn)
    dst = "%s/%s" % (dst_loc, ifn_norm)

    s3_dst = "%s/%s" % (create_time,ifn_norm)
    trans_dst = "%s/%s" % (proc_loc,ifn_norm)

    start_time = time.time()

    try:
        transcode(src,trans_dst)
    except:
        return
    trans_time = time.time() - start_time
    try:
        upload_to_ftp(trans_dst,s3_dst)
        # post request will be performed if no exception will raise in upload_to_ftp method

        # parameters for this call should be set in config file, because i don't know the url
        perform_post_req(trans_dst,s3_dst)

    except NameError as s3error:
        logger.error("Upload failed for %s , with exception %s" % (trans_dst, s3error))
        oflist.remove(ifn)
        hsize.pop(ifn)
        return

    upload_time = (time.time() - start_time) - trans_time

    logger.info("Uploading completed for %s, stats - transcode time : %.3f seconds, upload time : %.3f seconds" %(ifn,trans_time,upload_time))
    logger.info("Moving \"%s\" to \"%s\"" % (trans_dst, dst))
    rc = os.system("mv \"%s\" \"%s\"" %(trans_dst, dst))
    if rc != 0:
        logger.error("Can't move file %s - Exiting" %(trans_dst))
    else:
        logger.info("Moved file %s" %(trans_dst))
        oflist.remove(ifn)
        hsize.pop(ifn)
    return
```

ftp server is working fine , tested all the way ,

can you please advise

Comment: Could you update the code with actual part that call `upload_to_ftp` with actual values of `trans_dst`, `s3_dst` ?

Comment: updated , can you have look ?

Comment: all vars defined in config.yml

Answer (score 1):

According to the function `upload_to_ftp` definition, it expected server ip as the second parameter.

But in the calling part, file(or directory) path is passed.

```
upload_to_ftp(trans_dst,s3_dst)
                        ^^^^^^
```

Change `s3_dst` with the server ip.

Comment: thats works for me , but i face another issue , error_perm: 553 Could not create file. if i upload through script it will though this error , but if i used the same creds through ftp client it will upload normally i  notice when i list dir by script its shows owner is 1001:1001 !

Comment: @Jecki, Make sure the target directory exist and path is correct.

Comment: i've tested it with ftp client all is correct even i  added   _ftp.dir()   before start uploading to make sure im targeting the correct path ,

Comment: @Jecki, Try to replace `_ftp.storbinary('STOR '+ file_path, upload_file, 1024)` with `_ftp.storbinary('STOR '+ file_name, upload_file, 1024)`

Comment: @Jecki, If that does not work, `ftp.cwd(file_path.rsplit('/', 1)[0]); _ftp.storbinary('STOR '+ file_name, upload_file, 1024)`

Comment: 1st one fixed the issue , can you explain the issue ?

Comment: @Jecki, `file_path` is local file path, not remote file path; so instead of using the local path, I suggested to use `file_name` which does contain only file name, not directory path to it.